# Einstein Trailhead - Impossible to find the Assisted Setup

Tags: trailhead, einstein, setup

It's been about one hour and a half that I tried, with three different account made for the trailhead, and nothing's working for me ;

I am at this step of [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/projects/prioritize-leads-with-einstein-lead-scoring/steps/configure-einstein-lead-scoring) (one of the first steps !!)

[image]

It really is impossible for me to find in the Setup  the 'Assisted Setup' button...

It's part of this :

```
Assign Permission Sets
Great, you’re all set with your brand-new special org. Before you can set up Einstein Lead Scoring, you must give yourself and your sales rep access to Sales Cloud Einstein.

From Setup, enter Permission Sets in the Quick Find box, then select Permission Sets.
Click the Sales Cloud Einstein Permission Set.
Click Manage Assignments to assign the permission set to users.
Click Add Assignments.
Select the checkbox next to Pepper, Belle and your name, then click Assign.
Click Done.
```

If you know what I'm doing wrong, thanks a lot for your help, I'm desperate.

Nb : tried [those steps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=einstein_sales_setup_start_setup_assistant.htm&type=5) ... Nothing for me.

EDIT 19 July, 10:18 :

Yes, it's an account made using the specific trailhead form, and I've add permission set :

[image]

EDIT 19 JULY 11:14 :
My first issue is solved (don't know how tho)
But now, can't find why my process builder is not working.

Did the steps rigorously 3 times. Trailhead sometimes really is a time killing 
-_-

[image]

Comment: (a) Did you explicitly sign up [on this form](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/einsteinleadscoring)? A "normal" trailhead org *will not work* for this purpose. (b) Did you assign the permission set to your user account, as specified in the text? Until you do that, you won't have the permissions you need to go to the next step.

Comment: Also, for Trailhead-specific issues, you can go to the [help page](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help) and submit a case or post a message to the community discussion group.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I did sign up on the good form ; I did this trailhead just after doing on other that required a 'special' log. And yes, I did assign the permission set to my user account. I will try again today, but I tried to do step by step, exactly as told in the trailhead... I'm the only one having troubles ?

Comment: Wow.
I don't understand what I changed, but I'm abble to see the Assisted Setup and continue for the badge !
Thanks sfdcfox & David Cheng

-is there a way to close my case ?

Comment: But I can't finish ...
Look my edit. Again, something's killing me and I can't find what. Tried 3 times to again do step by step the Process... Rigorously -_-

Comment: OK solved my issue : I did everything right, except reading my emails and understanding the link ->

'Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 0051t000000tfuo/00D1t000000DTgS

Failed to invoke future method 'public static void createScoreAndFactors(List<Id>)' on class 'LeadScoreGenerator' for job id '7071t000000dW2r'

caused by: System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://eu16.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/composite/tree/ScoreIntelligence '

So I had this adress to the Security and WELL DONE